# Url rewrite for django ajax site in dev server

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm developing an Ajax site where routing is controlled with JavaScript.
I want every request to be sent to the IndexView except those declared in the `urls.py` file.
Here is my urls.py configuration:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^api/', include('api.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view()),
)
```

If I change the regex to `url(r'^', IndexView.as_view())` it works but files in MEDIA_ROOT won't be displayed.
I know in production I can config the server to serve the static files the way I want but I want it to work with the dev server.

Answer (score 0):

Silly solution. Adding `url(r'^', IndexView.as_view())` after,

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'%s(?P<path>.*)' % settings.MEDIA_URL[1:], 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    )
```

did the job.
But I'm open to better ways for managing routing with this kind of ajax applications.